# Query for records added in the 30 day

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I would like to check how many records added to all the BUs in the last 30 days.

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey,
EmailAddress,
DateAdded
FROM
YourSubscriberDataExtension
WHERE
DateAdded >= DATEADD(day, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are seeing? Please mention what you have tried and what error do you get.

Comment: I would like to add 30 days criteria in my query, something like; 

'SELECT CreatedDate AS Date
COUNT(SubscriberId) AS NumberOfSubscribers
FROM _subscribers
WHERE Status = 'Active'
AND Createddate BETWEEN 2023-03-01 AND 2023-04-30
GROUP BY Status'

Comment: You can use a DateAdd or DateDiff functions. Please give it a try and update your original question with the new query in case you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM Ent._Subscribers
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, DateJoined, GETDATE()) = 30